# Pattern Match With Data

Tags: haskell

How do I pattern match against a data type?

```
data Fruit = Apple | Banana | Orange 

isYellow :: Fruit -> Bool
isYellow x
  | x == Banana = True
  | otherwise = False
```

Comment: What is exactly your question? Have you tried to pattern match on it and failed in some way? Your example does not even compile since you didn't instantiate `Eq` for the `Fruit` type so you don't have `(==)`.

Comment: `isYellow Banana = True`; `isYellow _ = False` – does that answer your question?